# Does Form.hide allow code to continue "beyond" a Form.Show Modal in vb6?

Tags: vb6, modal-dialog

I'm doing a **Form.Show Modal** to force code execution until the user closes the shown form.

This form gets shown over again, so I'm thinking I'll just HIDE it. This seems to work OK, but wanted to confirm.

So:

1. frmMessage.Show MODAL
2. *user clicks OK and frmMessage.Hide*
3. code continues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either close or hide the modal form to allow the calling code to continue executing. At some point before your application closes you should make sure you unload any hidden forms though. I've had issues in my application with the application not always shutting down correctly when forms are still loaded and hidden. Might just depend on what resources your hidden forms are using.

Comment: Plus one. The VB6 user guide topic on [Form.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244181(v=vs.60).aspx) says *When Show displays a modal form, no subsequent code is executed until the form is hidden or unloaded.*  And yes, hidden forms always stop your program shutting down (I think not just sometimes but always). The VB6 user guide topic [life cycle of VB6 forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242139(v=vs.60).aspx) gives lots of relevant details

Comment: @MarkJ The `End` statement will unload all forms, hidden or otherwise, modal or not, and terminate execution, without calling any of those forms' unload event handlers.  As such, it is not to be recommended, but it still will do this.  Better to iterate the forms collection and unload each one specifically as part of a shutdown routine.

Comment: Good point, @Marc, I already have code that loops through all forms and closes them.